# Colorfunction in DensityPlot3D not acting as expect

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

Im trying to set the color function of a `DensityPlot3D` output so that it colors the positive values one color and colors the negative values a different color. However, I cant seem to get it to work properly. For example, the relevant code is:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  Parallelepiped[{-3, -3, -4}, {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 8}}];

DensityPlot3D[x*y*z,
              {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
              PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
              PlotRange -> All, 
              OpacityFunction -> Function[f, If[Abs[f] > 0.4, Abs@Tanh[f], 0]], 
              PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
              ImageSize -> Medium, 
              AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
              ColorFunction -> Function[f, Which[Sign[f] == 1, Black, Sign[f] == -1, Blue, Sign[f] == 0, Gray]]
]
```

Here, the color function I'm telling it to use is

```
Function[f, Which[Sign[f] == 1, Black, Sign[f] == -1, Blue, Sign[f] == 0, Gray]]
```

So take the positive values of the product `x*y*z` and color them Black, take the negative values and color them blue, and take everything else to gray.

This code, when executed by itself, produces

[image] [image]

which isn't what I want :( . Am I misunderstanding the arguments of the color function? I read the Doc's and I think I'm using it correctly, but I guess not. I also tried the function

```
(Which[Sign[#] == -1, Blue, Sign[#] == 0, Gray, Sign[#] == 1, 
   Black] &)
```

with the same result.
Im also having an issue with the `OpacityFunction`, as you may be able to tell in the example image above. The OpacityFunction in the example code should produce an image which is basically transparent in the very center and solid at the faces of the cube (so we should just see a black cube), but the image shows the corners of the cube are being set to 0 opacity. E.g., the point (-2,-2,-2) should have opacity `|Tanh[-8]|~1`

Im just using an example function above, the real function is way more complicated. I'll attach the output of actual function I need to color below:

[image: here] [image: legend]

Im using an opacity function to throw away any values really close to zero, leaving behind the interesting bits.

I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I realized it is because the arguments supplied to the `ColorFunction` are *Scaled* versions of the plotted values. So the values I'm seeing in the plot are not the exact values the `ColorFunction` is operating on. To stop the scaling, I simply set

`ColorFunctionScaling-> False`

`OpacityFunctionScaling -> False`

and that fixed the issue.

So now, the following code

```
DensityPlot3D[x*y*z, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
             PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
             PlotRange -> All, 
             OpacityFunction -> Function[f, If[Abs[f] > 0.5, N[ Abs[Tanh[f]]], 0]], 
             PlotLegends -> Automatic,
             ImageSize -> Medium, 
             AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
             ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, If[f > 0, Green, Blue]], 
             ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
             OpacityFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

produces the image

[image: output] [image: legend]

which translates over to the actual function I want to use perfectly. You can see, the areas with positive values of x*y*z are colored green and the areas with negative values of x*y*z are colored blue. Additionally, the Opacity behaves as desired too.

These links helped me solve my issue:

1. [Issues with ColorFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104561/issues-with-colorfunction?rq=1)
2. [Piecewise ColorFunction for Plot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75808/piecewise-colorfunction-for-plot3d?rq=1)

I hope this answer helps others who are having similar issues.